# Count array elements where there are significant 0 bits (below the highest 1 bit)

Tags: c++, assembly, visual-c++, x86, masm

An array of 3 bytes is specified.  Count the number of bytes where there's a zeros after any one.  i.e. where the bits below the most-significant `1` are not all `1`.

`{00000100, 00000011, 00001000}` - for this array the answer is 2.

My code gives 1, but it is incorrect; how to fix that?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int res = 0, res1 = 0;
    _int8 arr[3] = { 4, 3, 8 };
__asm {
    mov ecx, 3 
    mov esi, 0
    start_outer:
        mov bx, 8 
        mov al, arr[esi]
    start_inner :
        shl al, 1 
        jnb zero 
        jc one 
    one :
        dec bx к
        test bx, bx
        jnz start_inner 
        jmp end_ 
    zero :
        dec bx 
        test bx, bx
        jz end_
        inc res 
        shl al, 1 
        jnb was_zero 
        jc start_inner 
    was_zero :
        dec bx 
        dec res 
        jmp start_inner 
    end_ :
        inc esi
        loop start_outer
}
cout << res << endl;
system("pause");
}
```

Comment: _"calculate the number of zeros which go after one"_ Which 1? Why is the expected answer 2?

Comment: The answer is 2, because in the array `(00000100, 00000011, 00001000)` the first item `00000100` has at least one zero after a one, `00000011` has 0 zeroes after a one, and `00001000` has, again, at least one zero after a one.

Comment: Search the internet for "c++ bit twiddling".  There should be some good algorithms for bit counting.

Comment: @zx485 That's a possibility, and would make sense, but it doesn't really add up against the description in the question.

Comment: If what zx485 said is the actual logic behind this, then what you're really looking for is the number of bytes in the array that are even and non-zero. You don't need to go through every bit to find that. All you need for each byte is an `shr` by 1, followed by `jc false` `jz false`.

Comment: @Michael I don't understand what `jc false` and `jz false` do

Comment: When placed after the `shr` I mentioned, if the current byte was either odd or zero they jump to some label (pick whatever name you like for it) where you don't increment the result.

Comment: @Michael 10000001 is odd, but it counts (second bit 0 goes after first bit 1)

Comment: Note that it's not clear from your question how e.g. `10000001` should be treated. My suggested method would not increment the count for that byte.

Comment: @Michael yes, that's why you idea is not correct. I need to count ALL zeroes which goes after 1. zx485  explained quite well, how the program should count.

Comment: Based on the additional information, it seems like the values you want to exclude from your count are all the values on the form `(2^N)-1`, where N=0..8. You should be able to check for that fairly efficiently (e.g. `if ((value & (value + 1)) == 0)`).

Comment: I rephrased the question's English description of the problem to match the problem @zx485 described.  The original seemed to be describing something completely different from what you actually want, like treating the whole array as a single 24-bit value and counting the total number of zeros, rather than byte-elements with zeros.  Or counting trailing zeros after the *last* 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next try.

Please try to explain better next time. Many many people did not understand your question. Anyway. I hope that I understood now.

I will explain the used algorithm for one byte. Later in the program, we will run simple a outer loop 3 times, to work on all values. And, I will of course show the result in assembler. And, this is one of many possible solutions.

We can observe the following:
Your satement *"Count the number of bytes where there's a zeros after any one."* means, that you want to count the number of transition of a bit from 1 to 0 in one byte. And this, if we look at the bits from the msb to the lsb. So, from left to right.

If we formulate this vice versa, then we can also count the number of transitions from 0 to 1, if we go from right to left.

A transition from 0 to 1 can always be calculated by "and"ing the new value with the negated old value. Example:

```
OldValue NewValue NotOldValue And
       0 0        1           0
       0 1        1           1   --> Rising edge
       1 0        0           0
       1 1        0           0
```

We can also say in words, if the old, previous vale was not set, and the new value is set, then we have a rising edge.

We can look at one bit (of a byte) after the other, if we shift right the byte. Then, the new Value (the new lowest bit) will be the LSB. We remember the old previous bit, and the do the test. Then we set old = new, read again the new value, do the test and so on and so on. This we do for all bits.

In C++ this could look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

using byte = unsigned char;

byte countForByte(byte b) {
    // Initialize counter variable to 0
    byte counter{};

    // Get the first old value. The lowest bit of the orignal array entry
    byte oldValue = b & 1;

    // Check all 8 bits
    for (int i=0; i<8; ++i) {

        // Calculate a new value. First shift to right
        b = b >> 1;

        // Then mask out lowest bit
        byte newValue = b & 1;

        // Now apply our algorithm. The result will always be 0 or one. Add to result
        counter += (newValue & !oldValue);

        // The next old value is the current value from this time
        oldValue = newValue;
    } 
    return counter;
}

int main() {
    unsigned int x;
    std::cin >> x;
    std::cout << std::bitset<8>(x).to_string() << "\n";
    byte s = countForByte(x);
    std::cout << static_cast<int>(s) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

So, and for whatever reason, you want a solution in assembler. Also here, you need to tell the people why you want to have it, what compiler you use and what target microprocessor you use. Otherwise, how can people give the correct answer?

Anyway. Here the solution for X86 architecture. Tested wis MS VS2019.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int res = 0;
    unsigned char arr[3] = { 139, 139, 139 };

    __asm {
            mov esi, 0;         index in array
            mov ecx, 3;         We will work with 3 array values
DoArray:
            mov ah, arr[esi];   Load array value at index
            mov bl, ah;         Old Value
            and bl, 1;          Get lowest bit of old value

            push ecx;           Save loop Counter for outer loop
            mov ecx, 7;         7Loop runs to get the result for one byte
DoTest:
            shr ah, 1;          This was the original given byte
            mov al, ah;         Get the lowest bit from the new shifted value
            and al, 1;          This is now new value
            not bl;             Invert the old value
            and bl, al;         Check for rising edge
            movzx edi, bl
            add res, edi;       Calculate new result
            mov bl, al;         Old value = new value
            loop DoTest

            inc esi;            Next index in array
            pop ecx;            Get outer loop counter

            loop DoArray;       Outer loop
    }
    std::cout << res << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

And for this work, I want 100 upvotes and an accepted answer . . .

Answer (score 1):

Basically, user @Michael gave already the correct answer. So all credits go to him.

You can find a lot of bit fiddling posts here on stack overflow. But a very good description for such kind of activities, you may find in the book *"Hacker’s Delight"* by *"Henry S. Warren, Jr."*. I have here the 2nd edition.

The solution is presented in chapter 2, *"Basics"*, then *"2–1 Manipulating Rightmost Bits"*

And if you manually check, what values do **NOT** fullfill your condition, then you will find out that these are

0,1,3,7,15,31,63,127,255,

or, in binary

0b0000'0000, 0b0000'0001, 0b0000'0011, 0b0000'0111, 0b0000'1111, 0b0001'1111, 0b0011'1111, 0b0111'1111, 0b1111'1111,

And we detect that these values correspond to 2^n - 1. And, according to *"Hacker’s Delight"*, we can find that with the simple formular

```
(x & (x + 1)) != 0
```

So, we can translate that to the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    unsigned char arr[3];

    unsigned int x, y, z;
    std::cin >> x >> y >> z;

    arr[0] = static_cast<unsigned char>(x);
    arr[1] = static_cast<unsigned char>(y);
    arr[2] = static_cast<unsigned char>(z);

    unsigned char res = ((arr[0] & (arr[0] + 1)) != 0) +  ((arr[1] & (arr[1] + 1)) != 0) + ((arr[2] & (arr[2] + 1)) != 0);

    std::cout << static_cast<unsigned int>(res) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Very important. You do not need assembler code. Optimizing compiler will nearly always outperform your handwritten code.

You can check many different versions on [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/). Here you could see, that your code example with static values would be completely optimized away. The compiler would simply calculate everthing in compile time and simply show 2 as result. So, caveat. Compiler explorer will show you the assembly language generated by different compilers and for selected hardware. You can take that if you want.

Please additionally note: The above sketched algorithm does not need any branch. Except, if you want to iterate over an array/vector. For this, you could write a small lambda and use algorithms from the C++ standard library.

C++ solution

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <iterator>

int main() {

    // Define Lambda to check conditions
    auto add = [](const size_t& sum, const unsigned char& x) -> size_t {
        return sum + static_cast<size_t>(((x & (x + 1)) == 0) ? 0U : 1U); };

    // Vector with any number of test values
    std::vector<unsigned char> test{ 4, 3, 8 };

    // Calculate and show result
    std::cout << std::accumulate(test.begin(), test.end(), 0U, add) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you're going to link https://godbolt.org/, link to *your code* there.  That's why it has the permalink button to make short or full links.  (Full links preferred to avoid link-rot.)

Comment: The problem is that you count number of 'right' numbers (which fulfill this condition (x & (x + 1)) != 0), but I need to count all zeroes which comes after 1. For example if I have a number 139 (which is  ‭10001011‬ in binary) I count it as 2 (because we have two zeros which go after 1). Then I have again (for example) second number 139 and third number 139. The total answer is 6.   "like treating the whole array as a single 24-bit value and counting the total number of zeros",  actually this I need to code in assembly (not in c++)

Comment: @EmilyFitz: you said in comments that zx485 had correctly explained how to get a result!!  Now you're saying something that wasn't true after all.  Please edit your question with this new better explanation of what exactly the algorithm you need is.  Apparently my edit to the question (based on your comments) was not correct after all, and the original wording in the question was closer to what you wanted after all, but didn't seem to match exactly.